# android current location GPS but return null

Tags: android, get, gps, location

i develop an app to retrieve current  location via GPS but it return null  i want my app use gps only not 3g or wifi   i used  bestprovider but it retrieve only when i run it and not always work

this is the java code :

```
    package com.example.loc2;

    import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
   import android.location.LocationManager;
  import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters  
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            new MyLocationListener()
    );

retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       // @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCurrentLocation();
        }
});        

}    

protected void showCurrentLocation() {

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format(
                "Current Location \n Longitude: "+location.getLongitude()+" \n Latitude:"+
                 location.getLatitude());

        Toast.makeText(  MainActivity.this,message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}   

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}
```

and this is the manifest:
i used this permission

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.loc2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at this, it will help you

```
 LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            mlocListener);

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            mAddresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        String cityName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
                .getLocality() : TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
        String countryName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
                .getCountryName() : Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()
                .toString();


        mCurrentSpeed.setText("Longitude"+loc.getLongitude()+" Latitude"+loc.getLatitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but mAddresses from what type becouse it's not work

Comment: mAddresses is of type of Address

Comment: Please note: I've experience tons of issues using the built in GeoCoder service, as it likes to randomly disable itself. Restarting the device will fix the GeoCoder issue, but the better approach is to just send a web request to Google's web GeoCoder service, as I've never seen that fail.

Answer (score 0):

You must have proper sequence/order of calling methods.

```
onCreate() {   
    GoogleApiAvailability mGoogleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();   

    byte b = (byte) mGoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);    


    if (b == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {    
        try {   
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());    

            //setUpMap();    

            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {    
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();   
            }    
        }catch(Exception e) {    
            e.printStackTrace();   
        }   
    }   
}   

@Override   
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {       
    checkForLocationPermission();      

    Location location1 = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);    

    if(location1 != null) {       
        currentLatitude = location1.getLatitude();    
        currentLongitude = location1.getLongitude();    
    }    

    startLocationUpdtes();    
    setUpMap();    

}    


@Override    
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {    
//super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);    

    switch(requestCode) {    
        case MY_LAST_KNOWN_LOCATION_PERMISSION:    
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {    

                //Permission was allowed    
                isLocationAccessAllowed = true;    
            } else {    
                //Permission was denied      
            }     
    }     
}    

@Override    
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {    

}    

@Override    
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {    

}    

@Override    
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {    

    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();    

    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();    

}     

private void checkForLocationPermission() {    
    boolean isFineLocationNotAllowed = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;    

    boolean isCoarseLocationNotAllowed = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;    

    if(isFineLocationNotAllowed && isCoarseLocationNotAllowed) {    

        //Permission is not granted yet    
        boolean shouldRequestForPermission = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);     

        if(shouldRequestForPermission) {    
            //user has allowed permission    

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_LAST_KNOWN_LOCATION_PERMISSION);   

        } else {    
            //user has denied permission    
        }    

    } else {    
        //permission is already granted    

        //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_LAST_KNOWN_LOCATION_PERMISSION);    
    }    
}
```

Comment: first set api using GoogleClientAPi then in OnConnected callback check for Loa=cation permission at runtime then prepare a location request

Answer (score 0):

step 1>  prepare GoogleClientAPI instance
 step 2> in onConnected callback check for location premission at runtime     using andorid runtime permission mechanism

step 3> get Location Location location1 = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

step 4> prepare Location Request as  LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(0)
                .setFastestInterval(0);

setp 5>  register for location updates as

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

step 6>  get MapFragment instance from layout as

SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);